# Why does startkde (now startplasma-x11) start python scripts at login?

Tags: kde5

I previously asked [what starts youtube-dl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694176/what-starts-youtube-dl-automatically-in-linux/), and got a great tip which helped me discover that it is started by:

```
...
   \_/bin/sh /etc/sddm/Xsession /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
      \_python /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl ?????
```

There must be an init-script somewhere, but I still haven't managed to find where; the documentation hasn't helped, and it seems I don't search for the right things in google. There just seem to be far too many things going on when KDE starts up.

Where are things like autostart scripts for KDE?

***Edit***

I finally figured this out. From memory, since I'm not at home - `Xsession` runs `/etc/profile`, among other things, where I have defined a number of shell functions, one of which is a wrapper around `youtube-dl`:

```
...
\ Not the real function, but something like it
function yt
{
  youtube-dl $1
}
...
```

This works fine when your login shell is `bash` or `ksh`, but `Xsession` runs `/etc/profile` through the old Bourne shell, `/bin/sh`. In this environment, `function yt` is not valid, it should be `yt()` instead; so, the `function yt` is ignored, but the call to `youtube-dl` inside isn't - it gets run with a garbled parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Things like autostart scripts for KDE are in the system settings app (systemsettings5)

Workspace -> Startup and Shutdown

One of the items there Desktop Session has an option "restore previous session"

It's only a checkbox but what it starts you can read in he  $HOME/.config/ksmserverrc configuration file.

ksmserverrc is the configuration file for the KDE session manager, **ksmserver**
That program does the following:

1. launch a display manager (in KDE the
   default is kwin)
2. autostarts desktop files in $HOME/.config/autostart
3. starts prestartup script files in  $HOME/.config/plasma-workspace/en
4. can restore the previous session

The other settings you'll find in systemsettings under Workspace -> Startup and Shutdown are coming from

1. **kded** a generic KDE daemon. The configuration file is  $HOME/.config/kded5rc
2. **kcminit** executes initialization services during startup kcminit --list can be used to show all initialization services
3. Your display manager.

I'm using version 5.21.4 of KDE system settings.